# What the long option " --debug" suppose to do in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(2)-release-(i686-pc-msys)
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
        bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        --dump-strings
        --help
        --init-file
        --login
        --noediting
        --noprofile
```

I notice there are two options for debug of my bash script. since I'm new to bash, I really want a debugger or things like that.

I have searched official document about bash 4.3, but I still don't know what the "--debug" long option suppose to do.

Comment: @User112638726 yes. just bash --debug, and do sth. and all is as usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git), `--debug` sets a `debugging` flag (in [`shell.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c)), but I can't find anywhere that flag is used. So it appears to not do anything.

`--debugger` activates support features for the [bash debugger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/); the latter is probably what you're looking for.